# How to store method pointers in a HashMap and call them

Tags: methods, rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to write a chip8 emulator and the borrow checker is giving me a hard time.

The idea is to decode an opcode through looking up a method pointer inside a `HashMap` and then executing this method pointer but I cannot get the mutable method pointers to work correctly:

```
struct Chip8 {
    opcode: u16,
    //... other fields
    jump_table: HashMap<u16, Box<fn(&mut Chip8)>>,
}
```

Function using the pointers:

```
fn execute_decoded(&mut self, key: u16) {
    let func = self.jump_table.get(&key);

    match func {
        Some(func) => func(self),
        None => {
            println!("invalid op: {}", self.opcode);
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(10000));
            return;
        }
    }();

    self.program_counter = self.program_counter + 2;
}
```

The checker complains:

```
 cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.jump_table` is also borrowed as immutable
   --> main.rs:168:36
    |
165 |             let func = self.jump_table.get(&key);
    |                        --------------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
168 |                 Some(func) => func(self),
    |                                    ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
178 |     }
    |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

I do not understand why this error is happening.

Why is `self.jump_table.get(&key)` borrowing at all? Based on the signature of `execute_decoded`, I was assuming that it works on a mutable borrowed version of `self` and no additional borrowing is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HashMap` in Rust owns everything inside of it. In order to get your function pointer you are borrowing it with `let func = self.jump_table.get(&key);`. So now, `func` is *immutably borrowing* `self.jump_table` (which is an element of `self`).

The issue is that you are then trying to pass all of `self` into `func`. This would be fine if you were passing in `self` immutably, as you can borrow `self` immutably as many times as you want. However, since you are trying to mutably borrow `self` the compiler will not allow you to do so since you have just immutably borrowed a *portion* of `self` (specifically `self.jump_table`).

One way to fix this is to split up your `Chip8` struct into smaller structs, such that you can pass all of the necessary information into `func` without also passing in `jump_table`.

Comment: Completing the thought, the compiler cannot guarantee that `func` won't *change* `self` such that it becomes invalidated, such as by clearing the hash map.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to `Box` the function pointers in the `HashMap`, that only introduces unneeded indirection.

As has [already been mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028612/155423), you are borrowing the function pointer. The thing is, there's no reason to. You can just copy the function pointer to disassociate it from the `HashMap`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Chip8 {
    jump_table: HashMap<u16, fn(&mut Chip8)>,
}

impl Chip8 {
    fn execute_decoded(&mut self, key: u16) {
        let func = self.jump_table.get(&key).map(|x| *x);

        match func {
            Some(func) => func(self),
            None => {
                println!("invalid op");
            }
        };
    }
}

fn main() {}
```